# USB CDC-ACM Class Driver on STM32F4

Tags: usb, stm32, host

Simply my project is to connect a Huawi USB modem to my STM32F407 Discovery board, and start using AT commands to send text SMS.

so here is what I've and what I want :)

- I've OTG USB capability on my board.
- I've the USB Host Controller Driver and Embedded USB Host Stack.

What I want or to know more about is:

- USB CDC-ACM Class Driver

Here is a simple diagram to give more overview:

[image]

I found many commercial drivers, whither by Micrium or by Micro Digital, but I'm sure there must be a free something of everything anywhere :)

I appreciate your help in advance :)

Comment: Have you looked at the USB Spec? I imagine there are 2 layers you need to implement: The USB protocol itself to do the communications and the actual protocol to send data.
For the first you likely will benefit from reading the USB spec and implementing the CDC-ACM Class. For the latter the datasheet would be helpful (or perhaps due to USB standard, the commands are standard). Otherwise, reverse engineering existing communications might be the only thing left.

Comment: Keep in mind you may have to trigger a mode switch on the device before it goes into the CDC-ACM mode.

Comment: I'm also in need of USB CDC host on STM32. Did you have any luck finding an example or have you implemented it yourself? If so, would you be willing to share your experience, and possibly source?

Comment: Did you check the STM32 example? And do you have experience with USB?

Answer (score 1):

ST recommend to use STM32CubeMX software to start a project.

In This software you can configure your MCU and select which library you want.
Maybe "*Communication Host Class(Virtual Port Com)*" will suit your needs but if it don't, you can still modify it.

PS: The USB host Stack is already made.